Проблема с ldconfig в archlinux
1dconfig: /us/11b/11bnep.so is for unknown machine 183. 
1dcontig: /usr/11b/11bbde.so.1 1s for unknown machine 183. 
idconfig: /ust/11b/libnfdump-1.6.23.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /us/lib/1ibosmogb.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/lib/librevm32.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11bpanel.so.5 Is for unknown machine 183. ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgdbwrap64.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/11b/libstderes164.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /us/lib/libconn.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/lib/libasm64.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/lib/libefence.so.0 is for uebnown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/lib/libncurses++N.so.5 is for unknown machine 183 1dconfig: /us/lib/libedfmt32.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/lib/libdislocker.so is for unknown machine 183. пр 1dconfig: /usr/lib/1ibosmocodec.so is for unknown machine 183. •adE 1dconfig: /us/11b/1ibosmousb.so.0 is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/11b/1ibosmogsm.so.18.0.0 is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /us/lib/11bjunkietools.so.0.0.0 is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/lib/libnep.so.2.3 is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /us/lib/libbrotlicommon.so.0.6.0 is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig; /us/11b/1ibefence.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11basm32.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/lib/libruby-2.6.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11bConn.so.1.0.39 is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11bnfdump.so is for unknown machine 183. ldconfig: /usr/11b/11b£ormw .so.5.9 is for unknown machine 183. 1dconf1g: /usr/11b/11bgconf-2.so.4 is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11bfvde.so is for unknown machine 183. 1dconfig: /uSr/11b/11bosmogsm,so,18 is for unknown machine 183, Ldconfig: /usr/11b/Libosmogsm,so is for unknown machine 183, 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11bneurses++,so,5 1s for unknown machine 183, ldconfig: /usr/lib/libpanelw
50.5 is for unknown machine 183, 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11btic for unknown machine 183, 1dconfig: /usr/11b/libbrotlidec,so,0,6,0 is for unknown machine 183, 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11bgconf-2 . so 1s for unknown machine 183, Ldconf1g: /usr/11b/11bosmocodec,so,0,3,1 is for unknown machine 183, 1dconf1g: /usr/11b/11baspect32,so is for unknown machine 183, 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11bmjo11n1:64.so 1s for unknown machine 183, 1dconfig: /usr/11b/11be2dbg32.so is for unknown machine 183, 1dconf1g: /usI/11b/11bosmocore.so,19 1s for unknown machine 183, Ldconfig: /usr/11b/11bmenu.so.5 1s for unknown machine 183.

Ошибка возникает при установке пакетов с помощью pacman из-за этого некоторые пакеты просто не устанавливаются

Вы прогнали текст ошибки через OCR что ли?

Нет я не прогонял
